# Jest test Cannot read property 'Object.<anonymous>' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

```
/Users/***/Desktop/projects/***/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:517
    const wrapper = this._environment.runScript(transformedFile.script)[
```

Sometimes if i'm run npm test jest given this error.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4710 if you have not yet found a solution; may help out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused by running an Animated animation in React Native. Not running that animation when jest is detected is the best solution I found for now. I tried not to run animation, and the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when not shallow rendering a component in a test.

My guess is that it's caused by the rendering of the children components, so I mocked the parent component of the render function and the tests started running fine.

You have a great example of mocking children components here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks